# how can I change the textfield background when selected

Tags: html, css, textfield

how can i change the background of textfield when selected? for example i clicked the text field for firstname, the background of that textfield should turn to gray, so that the user will know that it is the current text he is editing.

Here is my code so far.

```css
       .textbox {
         background: white;
         border: 1px solid #DDD;
         border-radius: 5px;
         box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DDD inset;
         color: #666;
         outline: none;
         height: 2.5em;
         width: 28em;
         margin-bottom: 2%;
       }
```

```html
<label for="first name">First Name *</label>
<br>
<input class="textbox" type=text autofocus id="Fname" name="Fname" maxlength="50" size="30" value="" required>
<br>

<label for="last name">Last Name *</label>
<br>
<input class="textbox" type=text autofocus id="Lname" name="Lname" maxlength="50" size="30" value="" required>
```

Comment: As already answered, you need to use the `:focus` pseudo-class. I would recommend you check all the pseudo classes of CSS to understand how they work and learn about the different possible states of a selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Answer (score 3):

Just like so:

```
 .textbox:focus {
     background: lightgray;
 }
```

> The :focus CSS pseudo-class is applied when an element has received
>   focus, either from the user selecting it with the use of a keyboard or
>   by activating with the mouse (e.g. a form input).
>   [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS pseudo-class [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) to apply styling when a textbox is focused. Notice that since you applied the autofocus property that the first name is automatically focused.

Ex:

```
.textbox:focus {
  background: gray;
}
```

```css
.textbox {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DDD inset;
  color: #666;
  outline: none;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 28em;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.textbox:focus {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<label for="first name"> First Name *</label>
<br>
<input class="textbox" type=text autofocus id="Fname" name="Fname" maxlength="50" size="30" value="" required>


<br>
<label for="last name"> Last Name *</label>
<br>
<input class="textbox" type=text autofocus id="Lname" name="Lname" maxlength="50" size="30" value="" required>
```